# Fix top buttons on scroll of list below

Tags: css, tailwind-css

There is a "header" on this list that I need locked. Below them is a user list that can scroll but the div's above need to stay fixed. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong and its driving me mad.

Bonus points if you can figure out why the 5 small buttons are not spaced properly cause I cant figure that out either. All of this is done in tailwind. I know there is a lot of code but it seemed easier to give a real world set as opposed to all the JavaScript to create that code. I have also included an image to show you the issue

[image]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />
    <aside class="hidden w-80 bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-l border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-800 overflow-y-auto lg:block">
        <div>
            <div class="sm:hidden">
                <label for="userlists" class="sr-only">Select a tab</label>
                <select id="userlists" name="userlists" class="block w-full focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-800">
                    <option>All</option>
                    <option>Watching</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!--User List Filter -->
            <div class="hidden sm:block">
                <nav class="relative z-0 shadow flex divide-x divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800" aria-label="UserLists">
                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10" aria-current="page">
                        <span>All</span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-indigo-500 absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10">
                        <span>Watching</span>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-transparent absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
                    </a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="justify-evenly">
                <span class="relative z-0 inline-flex shadow-sm rounded-md">
                    <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                        <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h6m4 0l4-4m0 0l4 4m-4-4v12"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                        <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h9m5-4v12m0 0l-4-4m4 4l4-4"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                        <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 10l4.553-2.276A1 1 0 0121 8.618v6.764a1 1 0 01-1.447.894L15 14M5 18h8a2 2 0 002-2V8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                        <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                        <svg
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 6V4m0 2a2 2 0 100 4m0-4a2 2 0 110 4m-6 8a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4m6 6v10m6-2a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4"></path>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--User List Users -->
        <ul class="flex-1 divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800 overflow-y-auto dark:bg-gray-900">
            <li>
                <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
                    <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
                        <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                        <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
                            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                                <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                    <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </span>
                                <div class="ml-4 truncate">
                                    <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
                                    <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
                            <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                                <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                        <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </button>
                            <!---->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
                        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
                            <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                            <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
                                <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                                    <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566753323558-f4e0952af115?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fG1hbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                        <span class="bg-gray-300 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </span>
                                    <div class="ml-4 truncate">
                                        <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RKMAdmin</p>
                                        <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">New York City, USA</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
                                <button id="headlessui-menu-button-3" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                    <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                                    <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                            <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </span>
                                </button>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sticky top-0 bg-white z-10` on parent.

Second issue is, you're not using the `space-evenly` together with `flex`. Move it next to the `inline-flex` container.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" />

<aside class="max-h-60 w-80 bg-gray-100 shadow-2xl border-l border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-800 overflow-y-auto lg:block">
  <div class="sticky top-0 bg-white z-10">
    <div>
      <label for="userlists" class="sr-only">Select a tab</label>
      <select id="userlists" name="userlists" class="block w-full focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-800">
        <option>All</option>
        <option>Watching</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <!--User List Filter -->
    <div class="sm:block">
      <nav class="relative z-0 shadow flex divide-x divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800" aria-label="UserLists">
        <a href="#" class="text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10" aria-current="page">
          <span>All</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-indigo-500 absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:dark:text-gray-50 group relative min-w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 py-4 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-center hover:bg-gray-50 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-gray-50 focus:z-10">
          <span>Watching</span>
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="bg-transparent absolute inset-x-0 bottom-0 h-0.5"></span>
        </a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="relative z-0 inline-flex justify-evenly w-full shadow-sm rounded-md">
                <button type="button" class="relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h6m4 0l4-4m0 0l4 4m-4-4v12"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 4h13M3 8h9m-9 4h9m5-4v12m0 0l-4-4m4 4l4-4"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 10l4.553-2.276A1 1 0 0121 8.618v6.764a1 1 0 01-1.447.894L15 14M5 18h8a2 2 0 002-2V8a2 2 0 00-2-2H5a2 2 0 00-2 2v8a2 2 0 002 2z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 4.354a4 4 0 110 5.292M15 21H3v-1a6 6 0 0112 0v1zm0 0h6v-1a6 6 0 00-9-5.197M13 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="-ml-px relative inline-flex items-center px-6 py-2 border border-gray-300 bg-white  dark:border-transparent dark:bg-gray-900 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:z-10 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" class="w-4 h-4 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 6V4m0 2a2 2 0 100 4m0-4a2 2 0 110 4m-6 8a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4m6 6v10m6-2a2 2 0 100-4m0 4a2 2 0 110-4m0 4v2m0-6V4"></path>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--User List Users -->
  <ul class="flex-1 divide-y divide-gray-200 dark:divide-gray-800 overflow-y-auto dark:bg-gray-900">
    <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                            <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                    <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                            <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                    <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                            <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                    <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                            <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                    <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
      <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                            <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1480455624313-e29b44bbfde1?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Nnx8bWFsZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                <span class="bg-green-400 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RealGayRedneck</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">Toronto, Canada</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-1" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                            <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                <svg
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                    <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                        </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="relative group py-6 px-5 flex items-center">
        <a href="#" class="-m-1 flex-1 block p-1">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 group-hover:bg-gray-50" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <div class="flex-1 flex items-center min-w-0 relative">
            <span class="flex-shrink-0 inline-block relative">
                                <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566753323558-f4e0952af115?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fG1hbGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=900&amp;q=60" alt="">
                                    <span class="bg-gray-300 absolute top-0 right-0 block h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full ring-2 ring-white" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </span>
            <div class="ml-4 truncate">
              <p class="text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-50 truncate">RKMAdmin</p>
              <p class="text-sm text-gray-500 truncate">New York City, USA</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="ml-2 flex-shrink-0 relative inline-block text-left">
          <button id="headlessui-menu-button-3" type="button" aria-haspopup="true" class="group relative w-14 h-8 bg-white rounded-full inline-flex items-center justify-center focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                <span class="sr-only">Open options menu</span>
                                <span class="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full rounded-full">
                                    <svg
                                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="w-5 h-5 text-gray-400 dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500">
                                        <path d="M10 6a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 12a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4zM10 18a2 2 0 110-4 2 2 0 010 4z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                </span>
                            </button>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: I never knew about sticky (more of a backend guy here) so thats very valuable. I thought fixed was how you went about it. Question: Does Sticky also apply to bottom-0

Comment: yeah you can use top or bottom values (also left and right for horizontal scroll) with sticky. all of them are valid.